# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' sonar plugin jenkins

Tags: jdbc, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube

I am using sonar plugin with jenkins. It always generates this error. It seems the plugin can't find the JDBC driver. I tried putting the JDBC driver in many possible places according to the many solutions I found in google, but it still generates this error.

```
C:\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\sonar-runner-2.4
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_21 Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1 x86
INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\sonar-runner-2.4\conf\sonar-  runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: C:\Jenkins\jobs\check2\workspace\sonar-   project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.3.2
10:18:10.612 INFO  - Load batch settings
10:18:14.265 INFO  - User cache: C:\.sonar\cache
10:18:14.321 INFO  - Install plugins
10:18:18.941 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
10:18:18.971 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 22.884s
Final Memory: 3M/15M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to connect to database
ERROR: Caused by: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
ERROR: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: have you added required jar file to your project?

Comment: You say in your question that you "tried putting JDBC driver to many possible places". The JDBC driver is a jar file.

Comment: sry my bad. yeah its in project

Comment: Please post the contents of your jenkins-sonar-plugin configuration AND the content of your sonar/conf/sonar.properties that configure the database. You might have missed the right configuration for one of the 2.

Comment: what I searching is from where does sonar plugin tries to find the JDBC libry? From our project or from its libry?

Comment: Definitely not from the project itself. We're using SonarRunner to analyze C# projects, and there aren't any JAR files in the project at all. I think the JARs get transferred from the SonarQube server.

Comment: That is right, the mysql driver is distributed with sonarqube server. That is why you should look in your servers database congiguration as well, or post the database parts of it so we can find the error in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue. It was in the sonar/conf/sonar.properties file (In sonarqube installation folder). Default url for database is wrong. I corrected it for mysql. Now it works fine. I spent days on this. Thanks TimHauschildt and SKempken.

Comment: It's odd that that did the trick. I figured it would be pulling that from my maven settings.xml file. Thanks for working that out.

Comment: ...also, don't be stupid like me to forget to restart SonarQube after changing those properties. ;-) (SonarQube 5.1 defaults to using H2, which indeed throws the above error when running, say, a Gradle build that defines it's using MySQL.)