# SonarQube fails to connect to database with error "cannot load jdbc driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.driver'"

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have started my sonarqube for windows-x86-64/StartSonar.bat its up.
Then in have runned the cmd from command prompt mvn sonar:sonar from project workspace.

But maven build is failing by the error message
**Fail to connect to database: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'**.

Note: In my sonar.properties file all lines are commented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' sonar plugin jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503007/cannot-load-jdbc-driver-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-sonar-plugin-jenkins)

Comment: please give the version of SonarQube and logs/sonar.log

Comment: my SonarQube version is 4.5.2